# Linear Probing. What is wrong with this program?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know what's wrong with this code. But I not getting all desired values as output. Help me with this code.

```
public class LinearProbing{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[13];
        int[] inputs = {18,41,22,44,59,32,31,73};
        int element = inputs[0] % 13;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 13;i++) {
            if(arr[element] != 0){
                element++;
                continue;
            }
            arr[element] = inputs[j++];
            element = inputs[j]%13;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+"  ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output that i want is :

```
0  0  41  0  0  18  44  59  32  22  31  73  0
```

and the output I am getting is:

```
0  0  41  0  0  18  44  59  32  22  0  0  0
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do? And what is it doing wrong?

Comment: what is the current result you are getting and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am implementing a hash table and applying conflict resolution technique Linear probing. I have edited my question to show the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually *debug* your code, you'd see that your loop exits prematurely, because 13 iterations won't do it. Actually, your code cannot give the output you request, as written, no matter how you modify the loop condition.

In order for your result to contain `73`, this statement must execute, where `j` references the last element of `inputs`:

```
arr[element] = inputs[j++];
```

However, if `j` referenced the last element, then the very next line *will* fail, because `j` now exceeds the length of `inputs`:

```
element = inputs[j]%13;
```

So, remove the loop condition, i.e. remove `i`, then break when `j` exceeds length of `inputs`:

```
int[] arr = new int[13];
int[] inputs = { 18, 41, 22, 44, 59, 32, 31, 73 };
int element = inputs[0] % 13;
for (int j = 0; ; ) {
    if (arr[element] != 0) {
        element++;
        continue;
    }
    arr[element] = inputs[j++];
    if (j == inputs.length)
        break;
    element = inputs[j] % 13;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
}
```

Or, better yet, now that you see that dumb `for` loop, with only an initializer, you'll realize that your `if (...) { ...; continue; }` statement is really a `while (...) { ... }` loop, so you can refactor the code to this, adding an extra guard condition for overflowing the `arr` array:

```
int[] arr = new int[13];
int[] inputs = { 18, 41, 22, 44, 59, 32, 31, 73 };
OUTER: for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    int element = inputs[i] % 13;
    while (arr[element] != 0)
        if (++element == arr.length)
            break OUTER;
    arr[element] = inputs[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: check your first for loop. Shouldn't the condition somehow involve the length of `inputs`?

Hint 2: doing `element++;` may lead to an out of bounds index.

Hint 3: what happens if you try to insert 14 elements?